# How to check if email is valid and working using python

Tags: python, dns, smtp

Am trying to validate some emails using python, I keep getting for all emails except for the ones matching my own email server

```
import re
import smtplib
import dns.resolver
import socket
import smtplib

# Address used for SMTP MAIL FROM command  
fromAddress = 'fromMyEmail@mydomain.com'#

input = open("input.txt", "r")
output = open("output.txt", "w+")

# Simple Regex for syntax checking
regex = '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$'

_VALID = 'VALID'
_IN_VALID = 'IN_VALID'

output.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format('email', 'domain', 'code', 'message', 'is_valid'))

for inputAddress in input.readlines():

    print('parsing ', inputAddress)

    try:
        code = 0
        message = None
        # SMTP lib setup (use debug level for full output)
        server = smtplib.SMTP()
        server.set_debuglevel(0)
        addressToVerify = str(inputAddress)

        # Syntax check
        match = re.match(regex, addressToVerify)
        if match == None:
            print('Bad Syntax')
            raise ValueError('Bad Syntax')

        # Get domain for DNS lookup
        splitAddress = addressToVerify.split('@')
        domain = str(splitAddress[1])
        print('Domain:', domain)

        # MX record lookup
        records = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX')
        print('exchanging')
        mxRecord = records[0].exchange
        mxRecord = str(mxRecord)
        print('mxRecord ', mxRecord)

        # SMTP Conversation
        server.connect(mxRecord)
        server.helo(server.local_hostname)  ### server.local_hostname(Get local server hostname)
        server.mail(fromAddress)
        code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
        server.quit()

        if code == 250:
            output.write(
                '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(addressToVerify.strip(), domain.strip(), code, str(message).strip(),
                                              _VALID))
        else:
            output.write(
                '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(addressToVerify.strip(), domain.strip(), code, str(message).strip(),
                                              _IN_VALID))

    except Exception as e:
        output.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(addressToVerify.strip(), domain, -1, str(e).strip(), _IN_VALID))

output.close()
```

but I keep getting the error `[Errno 111] Connection refused`

Comment: Probably there is a firewall blocking your access to the SMTP port

Comment: your regex is wrong, there is far more characters than what you put that are allowed on the left hand side. also not all domains have `MX` records. They may have more than one and then you have to take into account the priority (which you are not doing) or none at all (in which case you should use the `A` record). Also SMTP server may not let you test email addresses that way and deny access or start blacklisting you.